# mongoimport csv with headerline and datatype

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I'm trying to import a csv into mongodb using the following command:

> mongoimport --db users --collection contacts --file data.csv
>   --headerline

The database exists but not the collection, I want to create it and use the first row of the csv as the field names.  Why am I getting error:

> error validating settings: must specify --fields, --fieldFile or
>   --headerline to import this file type

I also would like to know:

- how to copy/import data from one collection into another (basically
  the syntax)
- how datatypes from csv are handled in mongodb when
  imported; do I need to specify datatypes for headers or will mongodb
  read it from csv types?

Answer (score 4):

To solve this:

1. Either make sure the first line of your `data.csv` file has field names of the data to be parsed and then execute:

   ```
   mongoimport --db users --collection contacts --type csv --headerline --file data.csv
   ```

Or

2. Define the list of field names that the values of csv would be parsed in using [`--fields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-fields)

   ```
   mongoimport --db users --collection contacts --type csv --file data.csv --fields["name","surname","etc"]
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I actually had a syntax error (missing quotes around the file source).  But I still want to understand if there is a way to specify data types while importing because some of the datatypes are not being read in correctly.

Comment: `--fields["name","surname","etc"]` didn't work for me, I had to use `--fields name,surname,etc`

Answer (score 1):

You should write command like this:

```
mongoimport --db users --collection contacts --type csv --file data.csv --fields "name","surname","etc"
```